# Using custom conda env in Jupiter Notebok

Tags: numpy, jupyter

I want to contribute to numpy. It is my first time. I have an issue with the forked repository. Here is what I did:

1. I forked numpy.
2. I cloned the fork in my PC.
3. I created a  conda virtual environment with this command conda create --name mynumpyenv python=3.10
4. I activated it. I then installed numpy from my local forked repository.  pip install -e .
5. I then launched jupyter notebook from within mynumpyenv  5- when I try to simply check the version using below command i get an error:
   import numpy; print(numpy.**version**)

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import numpy; print(numpy.**version**)

File G:\MyCode\myprofile\numpy\numpy_*init*_.py:97
93 from ._expired_attrs_2_0 import **expired_attributes**
96 # If a version with git hash was stored, use that instead
---> 97 from . import version
98 from .version import **version**
100 # We first need to detect if we're being called as part of the numpy setup
101 # procedure itself in a reliable manner.

ImportError: cannot import name 'version' from partially initialized module 'numpy' (most likely due to a circular import) (G:\MyCode\myprofile\numpy\numpy_*init*_.py)